# Аналог wave.setpos() для subprocess.Popen объекта

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли какой то аналог wave.setpos() для случая такого потока? Имеется временная метка начала-конца фрагмента в аудиофайле, нужно её установить в объекте subprocess.Popen, это вообще реально?

```
stream = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-i', sys.argv[1], '-ar', 8000, '-ac', '1', '-f', 's16le', '-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Создаю процесс, открывая аудиофайл через ffmpeg, получается через print(stream) = subprocess.Popen object. Был бы wave сделал бы тоже самое через setpos, покопался в документации что то ничего не нашёл. Может кто то подсказать?

Comment: Смотря для чего вам нужно временную метку передавать. Если например для обрезки файла, то ffmpeg есть соответствующие параметры для этого. Popen сам по себе ни о каких временных метках не знает, это универсальный класс для процессов, с чего бы ему знать, как работать с видео или аудио.

Comment: @insolor там суть такая, что вот тот первый метод, где yield он из файла достаёт [start, end] для фразы и передаёт этот промежуток в следующий метод, где уже берётся фрагмент этого потока(stream) и с ним ведётся работа повторно. смысл вообще всей задачи чтобы большой файл на маленькие поделить и потом маленькие параллельно обрабатывать, был бы wave через setpos можно было бы эти фрагменты нарезать и через async распараллелить.
да Popen не знает, но я же могу к stdout обращаться - там байты, я сначала хотел по байтам эти фрагменты делить, но в итоге пришёл к временным меткам.

Comment: Я с ffmpeg не очень много работал, и это было давно, не могу ничего конкретного тут подсказать. Посмотрите модуль https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg/, может будет чем-то полезно.

Comment: или https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: @insolor спасибо, посмотрю.