# Возврат значения из цикла без его завершения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите можно ли как то возвращая элемент из цикла его на этом не прекращать а продолжать выполнение? Пишу асинхронную программу, нужно вернуть `element` из функции и продолжить её выполнять, пробовал в очередь его класть, но она до конца работы не доступна так же(через `queue.put(element)`)

```
def my_fun()
    for element in elements:
        return element

my_fun()
```

Comment: Можно возвращать через yield, но с возвращенным из функции объектом нужно будет работать как с итерируемым объектом, а не одиночным элементом.

Comment: пробовал такой вариант - не подходит, нужны именно элементы дальше

Comment: Что именно пробовали, и что значит "нужны именно элементы дальше"?

Comment: ну я `yield` вместо `return` написал - ничего не дало)) в моём случае элементы это временные метки аудиофайла большого, я из него в этом методе должен вырезать границы фраз и в виде [start, end] передать дальше, хотелось бы при получении [start, end] их сразу же передать и продолжить выполнение метода - получить следующие [start, end] и снова передать дальше.

Comment: возможно, что следующее прозвучит не очень, но что мешает использовать print?

Comment: а зачем? мне нужно эти фрагменты передавать дальше и с ними работать, смотреть на них задачи нет :)

Comment: @insolor в общем не получится так сделать похоже. или в список или в очередь их синхронно складывать и потом уже передавать дальше всем скопом. посмотрите вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450232/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-wave-setpos-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-subprocess-popen-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0 может тоже будут мысли какие то

Comment: Судя по описанию, вам именно вариант через yield и должен подойти. Приведите пример как вы сейчас пытаетесь сделать, например, через очередь.

Comment: @insolor вот так примерно, не вижу смысла тоже так делать, `list.append` по скорости тоже самое сделает вместо `queue.put(x)`, а главыный вопрос, напомню, скорость:

queue = Queue()
for element in elements:
        queue.put(element)

while not queue.empty():
    print(queue.get())

Comment: На псевдокоде примерно так: https://pastebin.com/jmp4W4Y1

Comment: @insolor это то что нужно, благодарю! ошибка была в том что не правильно из генератора извлекал. посморите выше ссылочку на вопрос кинул, может будут тоже какие то идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример через `yield`:

```
def my_fun():
    for element in range(5):
        print(f"Создаем элемент {element}")
        yield element


for item in my_fun():
    print(f"Принимаем элемент {item}")
```

Вывод:

```
Создаем элемент 0
Принимаем элемент 0
Создаем элемент 1
Принимаем элемент 1
Создаем элемент 2
Принимаем элемент 2
Создаем элемент 3
Принимаем элемент 3
Создаем элемент 4
Принимаем элемент 4
```